# Passing DOM elements into a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, parse-platform, jquery-callback

I'm trying pass a DOM element in a callback function as shown below, but the value of the variable input of outside the callback functions ('success' and 'error') is different than inside the callback functions. It looks like certain properties are being stripped when it is passed as a parameter or there is some polymorphism going on.

How can I access the DOM element inside the callback functions?

```
$(":input").change(function() {        
    var DataObject = Parse.Object.extend("Data");
    var data = new DataObject();
    data.set($(this).id, $(this).val());

    var input = $(this);

    data.save({
        success: function(input) {
          // The save was successful.
          console.log(input.val());
          input.addClass("has-success has-feedback");
        },
        error: function(input, error) {
          // The save failed.  Error is an instance of Parse.Error.
          console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Which element you want to access inside callbacks?

Comment: Remove `input` as a parameter to your callback. Accessing the one in the outer scope is perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh ok. I swear I did that the first time. Thanks for that guys. That just leaves us with the question of why the variable changed when it was passed into the function.

Comment: Because it wasn't passing the one declared above. Since you're defining that function with the parameter `input`, it's creating a new local scope level `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I what to pass a parameter to a callback function (instead of let it use an outer scope variable) I use bind, useful also to change "this" object of the function.

So it will be:

```
  data.save({
    success: function(__input__parameter) {
      // The save was successful.
      console.log(__input__parameter.val());
      __input__parameter.addClass("has-success has-feedback");
    }.bind(null, input),

    error: function(__input__parameter, error) {
      // The save failed.  Error is an instance of Parse.Error.
      console.log(__input__parameter, error);
    }.bind(null, input)
})
```